# C++ ListView hide item

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi

I have created pretty much standard ListView.

```
    RECT rec;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rec);
    ListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, (LPCSTR)L"", (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT), 0, 0, rec.right, rec.bottom-23, hwnd, (HMENU)8553, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SendMessage(ListView, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES); // Set style
```

Now I insert few columns like that:

```
    LVCOLUMNW listColumnW = { 0 };
    listColumnW.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    listColumnW.pszText = L"Column1";
    listColumnW.cx = 150;
    listColumnW.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    SendMessage(ListView,LVM_INSERTCOLUMNW, 0, (LPARAM)&listColumnW);
```

after that I instert items and subitems

```
    LVITEMW lisW = { 0 };
    lisW.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM;
    lisW.pszText = item_text[i];
    lisW.iItem = i;
    lisW.lParam = i;
    SendMessage(ListView, LVM_INSERTITEMW, 0, (LPARAM)&lisW);
```

Now I'd like to implement some kind of search / filtering.
I see many people suggest to delete/reinsert items, however as there are quite a number of items in my listview that isn't the best solution.
While googling I learned that it should be possible to set groupid and set state of item (hide it).
However I'm not sure exactly how to do that, lets say I have 10 items in my listview and I want to hide some items, how exactly do I do that?

**EDIT:**

I have set LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW and created two groups, one is supposed to be shown and other one hidden.

```
    LVGROUP group = { 0 };
    group.cbSize = sizeof(LVGROUP);
    group.mask = LVGF_GROUPID;
    group.iGroupId = 10;//shown
    ListView_InsertGroup(ListView, -1, &group);
    group.iGroupId = 11;//hidden
    group.mask = LVGF_GROUPID | LVGF_STATE;
    group.stateMask = LVGS_HIDDEN;
    group.state = LVGS_HIDDEN;
    ListView_InsertGroup(ListView, -1, &group);
```

Now I have added some items to both groups, only problem is I can see them both (they are separated), while the other one is supposed to be hidden.

Comment: Try adding `LVGS_NOHEADER` and `LVGS_COLLAPSED` to the second group's `state`. Apparently simply setting `LVGS_HIDDEN` hides the group header but not the items in the group, but if you collapse the "hidden" group then its items will not be seen.

Comment: Thank You, it worked. However changing groupid isn't any faster than adding items and yes I've done all the optimisations like to change id only to items that change group. For ~40 000 items it can take over a minute, so I will indeed try Virtual lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`LVM_SETITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761186.aspx) to assign a list item to a specific group via the `LVITEM::iGroupId` member:

```
LVITEMW lisW = { 0 };
lisW.mask = ... | LVIF_GROUPID;
...
lisW.iItem = ...;
lisW.iGroupId = ...;
SendMessage(ListView, 0, (LPARAM)&lisW);
```

You can use [`LVM_INSERTGROUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761103.aspx) to insert a hidden group, or use [`LVM_SETGROUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761167.aspx) to hide an existing group, by setting its `LVGROUP::state` member to `LVGS_HIDDEN`:

```
LVGROUP grp = { 0 };
grp.cbSize = sizeof(grp);
grp.mask = LVGF_STATE;
grp.iGroupId = ...;
grp.stateMask = LVGS_HIDDEN | LVGS_NOHEADER | LVGS_COLLAPSED;
grp.state = LVGS_HIDDEN | LVGS_NOHEADER | LVGS_COLLAPSED;

SendMessage(ListView, LVM_INSERTGROUP, -1, (LPARAM)&grp);
or:
SendMessage(ListView, LVM_SETGROUPINFO, grp.iGroupId, (LPARAM)&grp);
```

Make sure you have enabled groups via [`LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774900.aspx) beforehand:

```
SendMessage(ListView, LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW, TRUE, 0);
```

That being said, when you have lots of items to display/search/filter in a ListView, you are usually better off using the ListView in [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style) instead.  You can pre-filter your data as needed, then use [`LVM_SETITEMCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761188.aspx) to specify the number of items you want to display, and then handle [`LVN_GETDISPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774818.aspx) to retrieve data for specific items when the ListView requests them from you. This way, you can do all of your searching/filtering within your datasource directly (in memory, in a database, etc), then simply invalidate the portions of the ListView that need to be refreshed onscreen using [`LVM_REDRAWITEMS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761145.aspx) when you have new data to display.  When you have items to add/remove, you simply re-send `LVM_SETITEMCOUNT`.  This is a much faster and flexible way to handle lots of list items.

[Using virtual lists](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7891/Using-virtual-lists)

Comment: I have created two groups, one that shows items and other that hides. Now I have problem that in fact my hidden group is not hidden. More info appended to first post.

Comment: Does LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW automatically cancel LVS_EX_GRIDLINES?

Comment: @amaninlove sounds like a question that is worth its own post.